# PHP MySql Like Query to Match Int in String

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to do what seems to be a simple MySQL query but cannot get it to work.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $match_column LIKE CONCAT('%',CAST($match_value AS CHAR),'%') ; <br />
```

The data in $match_column is a string of integers separated by a comma like this: 1,3,13,2. The data type in the table is varchar. If my search term is any one of those integers, such as 13, I want to include that row in result but it doesn't work.  The query string does work on data with a single integer in $match_column.  Using regEx might be the answer, but I  am nor proficient there. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What results are you seeing? None at all? On another note, keep in mind that you need to make sure "1" doesn't match "11,12,13"; your current code would have this issue even if it was working the way you intended.

Comment: You may want to look at FIND_IN_SET: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [FIND_IN_SET:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$match_value', $match_column);"
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess I'm rustier than I thought on my MySQL! Thanks.